# Find how many excel objects created in system

Tags: c#, excel, c#-2.0

Is there a way to get the count of excel objects created in system(taskmanager)? I want to get the count using C# code,I`m using C# version 2.0.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a version of the language more than ten years out of date?

Comment: Let me clarify my previous comment; it is a genuine question and not a rhetorical question intended as a criticism. I often have to make decisions about what revision of a language to support in tooling, and I often assume that very few people will be using language tools that are ten years out of date. If I know what reasons people have for using old tools, that helps me make decisions to better support those people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`System.Diagnostic.Process.GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL").Length;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry I got the error like "'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I`m using framework 2.0. Please correct me if I`m wrong.

Comment: @user3272854 - just use `.Length` instead (see my edit).